# WPF ObservableCollection<T> get ui reference from the added element

Tags: c#, wpf

I have encountered a problem, I would like to have an UI reference returned (after an item has been added to the ObservableCollection). So when an item has been added to the collection, I would like to get the "Border" reference.

Been trying to google for a solution but I cant find one.

The XAML, what I want is to return the Border in Datatemplate (is this possible)?

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="37,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="590" Height="29" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}" />
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Width="{Binding Style.Background.Width}" Margin="{Binding Style.Background.Position, Converter={StaticResource LeftMarginConverter}}" BorderThickness="{Binding Style.Background.BorderSize}" BorderBrush="{Binding Style.Background.BorderColor, Converter= {StaticResource MediaBrushConverter}}" Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Border.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush GradientStops="{Binding Style.Background.Background, Converter={StaticResource GradientConverter}}" Opacity="{Binding Style.Background.Opacity}"/>
                    </Border.Background>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" FontFamily="{Binding Style.Value.Font, Converter= {StaticResource FontConverter}}" Foreground="{Binding Style.Value.FontColor, Converter= {StaticResource MediaBrushConverter}}" FontSize="{Binding Style.Value.FontSize}" TextAlignment="Center"  Opacity="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextExtension}" FontFamily="{Binding Style.Value.Font, Converter= {StaticResource FontConverter}}" Foreground="#eaeaea" FontSize="{Binding Style.Value.FontSize}" TextAlignment="Center"  Opacity="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>


        foreach(var x in Elements) //  Elemets = ObservableCollection 
        {
            var i =FControls.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(x) as Border;

            MessageBox.Show(i.ToString()); /// Returns null
        }
```

Comment: IMO you should not be getting the UI elements or assuming that they are bound to a specific type of a control within your viewmodel. Just a side note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `ObservableCollection` doesn't provide the functionality you want. You may use `ItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem()` to obtain `ContentControl` that wraps your `DataTemplate`.

Comment: Ok, I understand.

I tried applying your code, but not sure if I am using it correctly (updated first post)

Comment: @user3447537 The return value of `ContainerFromItem()` is not a `Border`, but a `ItemsControl`. You can find your `Border` in the `ItemsControl.Content` property.

Comment: Got it working now (had to wait for the .Loaded event also), thanks :)